# How will i successfully upload Model to an Api that includes List of IFormFiles

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core

I have been trying to serialize and post my model into my API but it keeps rejecting it with an error. this is a project i am working on and i will like for someone to point me to the right direction. i have searched online and also downloaded videos on YouTube but none works for me.

I am getting this error: StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.HttpConnectionResponseContent

Please don't show me a link to go because i have tried all. just tell me a solution that works.
N.B
i have both IFormFIle and IFormFileCollection in my model but with [jsonignore] annotation on it. i don't know what is causing the error.

````
   ``` 
   [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddNew(Room model)
    {
        string apiResponse = "";
        var imageData = new Room
        {
            RoomNumber = model.RoomNumber,
            PricePerNight = model.PricePerNight,
            Description = model.Description,

        };
        IFormFile coverphotofile = model.coverphotofile;
        List<IFormFile> multipleFiles = new List<IFormFile>();
        multipleFiles = model.multipleFiles;
        var fileName2 = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(coverphotofile.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
        string suffix2 = fileName2.Split('.')[1];
        var stream2 = coverphotofile.OpenReadStream();

        byte[] imgArr2 = new byte[stream2.Length];
        stream2.Position = 0;
        stream2.Read(imgArr2, 0, (int)stream2.Length);
        stream2.Close();

        var imgBase64Content2 = Convert.ToBase64String(imgArr2);
        imageData.CoverPhotoURL = imgBase64Content2;
        imageData.CoverName = fileName2.Split('.')[0];
        List<RoomImage> fileDataList = new List<RoomImage>();
        foreach (var file in multipleFiles)
        {
            var fileName = ContentDispositionHeaderValue.Parse(file.ContentDisposition).FileName.Trim('"');
            string suffix = fileName.Split('.')[1];
            var stream = file.OpenReadStream();
            byte[] imgArr = new byte[stream.Length];
            stream.Position = 0;
            stream.Read(imgArr, 0, (int)stream.Length);
            stream.Close();

            var imgBase64Content = Convert.ToBase64String(imgArr);

            var img = new RoomImage
            {
                Imageurl = imgBase64Content,
                ImageName = fileName.Split('.')[0]
            };
            fileDataList.Add(img);
            
        }
        imageData.Roomimages = fileDataList;
        var roomJsonC = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(imageData);
        StringContent content = new StringContent(roomJsonC, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        HttpResponseMessage response = _httpclient.PostAsync(_httpclient.BaseAddress + "Rooms/AddNewBook", content).Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            return View("it was succesfully created. THank You!");
        }
        
        return View((object)apiResponse);
    }
````

Answer (score 0):

You could try following sample to upload model contains `List<IformFile>` and `<IformFIle>`
Item.cs

```
    public class Item
    {
        public List<IFormFile> multipleFiles { get; set; }
        public IFormFile singleFile { get; set; }
    }
```

Controller

```
        [HttpPost("test")]
        public void test(Item item)
        {
        }
```

test.html

```
List of files<br>
<input id="file1" type="file"><br>
<input id="file2" type="file"><br>
Signle file<br>
<input id="file_single" type="file"><br>
<button type="submit" onclick="submit()">Submit</button>

<script>
function submit () { 

    var file1=document.getElementById("file1").files[0];
    var file2=document.getElementById("file2").files[0];
    var file_single=document.getElementById("file_single").files[0];

    var data = new FormData()

    data.append('item.multipleFiles', file1)
    data.append('item.multipleFiles', file2)

    data.append('item.singleFile', file_single)

    fetch('https://localhost:7247/test', {
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
    })
}
</script>
```

Test
[image]
[image]

-------------------Update use MVC---------------
1.create an MVC template from visual studio
2.Add `Item.cs` model

```
    public class Item
    {
        public List<IFormFile> multipleFiles { get; set; }
        public IFormFile singleFile { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
    }
```

3.Add post method to Home controller "index page" like below

```
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Index(Item item)
        {
            // initiate a multipart formdata content
            var content = new MultipartFormDataContent();

            //add a string to content
            var stringContent = new StringContent(item.Description, Encoding.UTF8);
            content.Add(stringContent, "item2.Description");

            //add single file to content
            var singlefileContent = new StreamContent(item.singleFile.OpenReadStream());
            content.Add(singlefileContent, "item2.singleFile", item.singleFile.FileName);


            //add multiple file to content
            foreach(var file in item.multipleFiles)
            {
                var fileContent = new StreamContent(file.OpenReadStream());
                content.Add(fileContent, "item2.multipleFiles", file.FileName);
            }


            var client = new HttpClient();
            await client.PostAsync("https://localhost:7249/test", content);
            return View();
        }
```

4.Create another api but use `(Item item2)`

```
        [HttpPost("test")]
        public void test(Item item2)
        {
            
        }
```

5. change the "index.cshtml" like below

```
@model Item
<form asp-action="Index" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    SingleFile<br />
    <input asp-for="singleFile" type="file"  /><br />
    MultipleFile<br />
    <input asp-for="multipleFiles" type="file" multiple/><br />
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Test
[image]

Comment: @AlvaMira What is the error information? I can modify the answer to a loop to choose files to append to the formdata,  I thought it would be easier to understand this way.

Comment: @AlvaMira Sure. May i confirm it is MVC(controller+.cshtml) or RazorPages(.cshtml+.cshtml.cs) structure?

Comment: @AlvaMira I update the answer you could have a try

Comment: @AlvaMira Yes, I miss understand your request. A little tricky .I modify the answer you could try.

Comment: @AlvaMira When using `[HttpPost("test")]` ,you need to delete the [Routes] attribute at top of controller. Sorry for that I am busy with some work. ,will get back to you when I finish.

Comment: @AlvaMira Sorry, I am not allowed to share github link. I actually posted all the codes needed to reproduce my same project.  It used .net 6 MVC template.  You could share your link again I will check as soon as possible.

Comment: @AlvaMira emmm, the link is 404 to me.

Comment: thanks for taking your time to visit my case. My bad. It was set to private. V sorry about that.  https://github.com/Humble2020/LOOK_APIsolution

Comment: @AlvaMira Really don't know how to solve. Once the Room model is added as parameter to the api. The api seems cannot be called. As you say ,the swagger cannot detect the endpoint, it is so strange.

Comment: thanks Qiang for your time in assisting me along the way. i fixed it. this took me a week to figure out